# SQL - Union All Users in One Table Without Irregular Null Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want null values to be at the end of the list, but places them between names.

```
KullaniciAdi      KisiAdi
------------      ------------
AHMET GÜNDÜZ      " Ned Hsoleb(Guzel Alli) " --+
AHMET GÜNDÜZ      Raghuvar Masala              |
.                 .                            |
.                 .                            | AHMET GÜNDÜZ Has 10 Friends
.                 .                            |
.                 .                            |
AHMET GÜNDÜZ      Mint Agro -------------------+
ALİ AKKUM         Mustafa Saidmurodov -----+
ALİ AKKUM         Tarimkoop Ihsangazi      |
.                 .                        |
.                 .                        | ALİ AKKUM Has 9 Friends
.                 .                        |
.                 .                        |
ALİ AKKUM         Ali Uçar  ---------------+
YASEMİN AYSEN     Pepinier El Fertas --+
.                 .                    |
.                 .                    | YASEMİN AYSEN Has 6 Friends
.                 .                    |
YASEMİN AYSEN     Sarker Tredres ------+
```

This is my query union - all users but with irregular null values ;

```css
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',MAX(CASE WHEN KullaniciAdi = '''  + p.KullaniciAdi + ''' THEN KisiAdi END) AS '  + QUOTENAME(p.KullaniciAdi) FROM Populer p FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'') 
set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM  (   SELECT KullaniciAdi,KisiAdi,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KullaniciAdi ORDER BY EklenmeTarihi) AS RowNum FROM Populer ) x GROUP BY RowNum ' 
EXECUTE(@query)
```

[image: My Query Result:]

But, I want as ;

```
AHMET GÜNDÜZ                    ALİ AKKUM             YASEMİN AYSEN
------------                    ------------          -------------
" Ned Hsoleb(Guzel Alli) "      Mustafa Saidmurodov   Pepinier El Fertas
Raghuvar Masala                 Tarimkoop Ihsangazi   .
.                               .                     . 
.                               .                     .
.                               .                     .
.                               .                     Sarker Tredres
.                               .                     NULL
.                               .                     NULL
.                               Ali Uçar              NULL
Mint Agro                       NULL                  NULL
```

I cant edit my query.Can you help me about this?

Comment: Add an order by clause in the sql query for these columns and check

Comment: Where ? Can you give me sample with code ?

Comment: You have been able to modify the query given to you in your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445751/sql-union-all-users-in-one-table) . Surely you can add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: ORDER BY still added ("ORDER BY EklenmeTarihi"). I cant understand ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve the result. The following SQL will display the NULL value at the end. I have just modified your SQL with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX); 
CREATE TABLE #tempPopuler (KullaniciAdi VARCHAR(50), KisiAdi VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('AHMET', 'Ned Hsoleb')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('AHMET', 'Raghuvar')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('AHMET', 'Mint Agro')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('ALI', 'Mustafa')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('ALI', 'Tarimkoop')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('YASEMIN', 'Pepinier')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('AHMET', 'A')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('AHMET', 'B')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('AHMET', 'C')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('ALI', 'A')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('ALI', 'B')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('YASEMIN', 'A')
INSERT INTO #tempPopuler VALUES('YASEMIN', 'B')

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',(SELECT KisiAdi FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KisiAdi ASC) AS rownumber, KullaniciAdi, KisiAdi FROM [#tempPopuler] where KullaniciAdi = '''  + p.KullaniciAdi + ''') AS foo WHERE rownumber = x.ROW and  KullaniciAdi ='''  + p.KullaniciAdi + ''') AS'  + QUOTENAME(p.KullaniciAdi) FROM #tempPopuler p FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'') 
set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM  (SELECT KullaniciAdi,KisiAdi, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY KisiAdi ASC) AS [ROW] FROM #tempPopuler) x' 

EXECUTE(@query)

DROP TABLE #tempPopuler
```

Output

[image]

Comment: And second **ORDER BY KullaniciAdi ASC** dont work :( Also will be **ORDER BY KisiAdi ASC**

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN, I have changed the code. Check now

Comment: Columns are alphabetical on your table.But when I tried on my table,not working :( . Can I sent you my datas ? and Can you test your code on my table ?

Answer (score 0):

After your group by statement you need to add an order by clause like this, so that null values will get pushed to the end.

```
ORDER BY 
ISNULL(AHMET GÜNDÜZ ,'zzzzz'),ISNULL(ALİ AKKUM  ,'zzzzz'),ISNULL(YASEMİN AYSEN,'zzzzz')
```

This query will out put all the not null values first and push the null values to the last rows. try this out.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @ordercols as NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SET @ordercols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',case when isnull([' + p.KullaniciAdi + '],''0'')=''0'' then ''0'' else ''1'' end ' FROM Populer p FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'') 
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',MAX(CASE WHEN KullaniciAdi = '''  + p.KullaniciAdi + ''' THEN KisiAdi END) AS '  + QUOTENAME(p.KullaniciAdi) FROM Populer p FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'') 
set @query = 'SELECT * from(SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM  (   SELECT KullaniciAdi,KisiAdi,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KullaniciAdi ORDER BY EklenmeTarihi) AS RowNum FROM Populer ) x GROUP BY RowNum)a order by concat(  ' +@ordercols+') desc'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: I have 100+ Users and this means query has 100+ 'ISNULL' word :(

Comment: You can make that dynamic as @cols, you just need to add a concatenation with isnulll for that out put

Comment: my sql skills not enough to realise your advice.Can you help me ?

Comment: Ajan Balakumaran are u here?

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN could you be able to create a fiddle for your table so that I can test out the query and give a solution.

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran . . . You should be doing this in the database.  You want to treat each column as a separate list.  However, databases are designed around *rows* with the columns describing a specific entity.  You should do this in the presentation layer.

Comment: @AjanBalakuman can you give me email ? For send create table and insert values’ queries

Comment: ajanbalakumaran@gmail.com, I need a create table statement with data and the query which gives the current output you are getting.

Comment: Columns are not alphabetical and `ORDER BY EklenmeTarihi` not working true  :(

Comment: Ordering columns in alphabetical order is not your requirement of this question, in this question you wanted to get all the Nulls to the last row. Ordering columns by alphabetic order should go as a different question. This query works fine with your table create and insert statement that you shared with me.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the following code to the operator *order by*: `case when KisiAdi is null then 0 else 1 end desc`

```
    DECLARE 
        @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX); 

    SET @cols = STUFF((
        SELECT distinct ', MAX(CASE WHEN KullaniciAdi = '''  + 
            p.KullaniciAdi + ''' THEN KisiAdi END) AS '  + 
            QUOTENAME(p.KullaniciAdi) 
        FROM Populer p FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'');

    SET @query = 
        'SELECT ' + @cols + 
        ' FROM  (   
            SELECT KullaniciAdi, KisiAdi, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY KullaniciAdi ORDER BY case when KisiAdi is null then 0 else 1 end desc, EklenmeTarihi) AS RowNum 
            FROM Populer ) x 
        GROUP BY RowNum '; 

    EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: What are the values in the column EklenmeTarihi?

Comment: Upload Date of Row

Comment: Can the column "EklenmeTarihi" have a value of null?

Comment: Impossible :(   I checked it

Comment: Can the column "KisiAdi" have a value of null?

Comment: In your example data there are gaps. Give us all the data.

Comment: Can the column "KisiAdi" have a value of null? -Cannot

Comment: I can give you. But how ? Can you give me e-mail ?