# How to return an array from a SQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, database, subquery

I'm trying to query for a list of person's names and all their friends from my database. I need their list of friends to be in an array adjacent to their row for formatting purposes.

Here is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(r.first_name, ' ', r.last_name) as name, 
          ( SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as friend_name 
                FROM friend_list WHERE friend = r.id) as friends 
        FROM friend_list r";
```

Because people have multiple friends, I need this to return an array of friends for each person. how would I do this?

Comment: MySQL has no datatype called "array", so you cannot do this.  You can, however, format the data as a string or return JSON, and then parse out an array.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the tip! How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Expanding on @GordonLinoff 's comment)

There is no way to directly retrieve an array.
What you can do is generate a "serialized" array inside the query using `GROUP_CONCAT`, and then unserialize it on your application.

--EDIT--
Upon further testing, I've noticed the below code doesn't work as intended. But the idea of serializing and then unserializing still stands.

> $sql = "        SELECT CONCAT(r.first_name, ' ', r.last_name) as name, 
>         GROUP_CONCAT (          CONCAT(f.first_name, ' ', f.last_name)
>             SEPARATOR '|'       ) as friends        FROM friend_list r      JOIN
>   friend_list f ON f.friend = r.id;"    ;
>
> And to "unserialize" it in PHP:
>
> `$friendsArray = explode('|', $r['friends'])`

Comment: You are missing the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar one to this before using the below script.
The logic will be the same just change the table/field names to fit your one;

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',MAX(CASE WHEN UserName = ''' 
                    + p.UserName + ''' THEN FriendName END) AS ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(p.UserName) FROM Popular p
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM 
            (SELECT UserName, FriendName
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY FriendName) AS RowNum
                FROM Popular GROUP BY USERNAME, FRIENDNAME
            ) x
            GROUP BY RowNum'

EXECUTE(@query);
```

It will result in columns of users with their friends in new rows as per this;

```
╔════════╦══════╦════════╗
║  John  ║ Khan ║ Philip ║
╠════════╬══════╬════════╣
║ Jeremy ║ Lemy ║ Brock  ║
║ Marry  ║ NULL ║ Ursula ║
║ Sarah  ║ NULL ║ NULL   ║
╚════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

original thread can be found here;
[SQL - Union All Users in One Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445751/sql-union-all-users-in-one-table/54446506#54446506)

Comment: (1) This answer is for SQL Server and not MySQL.  (2) If you are going to just repeat an answer, just close as a duplicate.  (3) If you want to help the user, then adjust the answer for his/her question.